# D3 Undefined Attribute in Tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add two attribute in my tooltip, but keep failing. I can show two out of four attributes in the tooltip, but not all of them. "id" and "rate" can be shown, but not "state" and "county". I think it is due to wrong data loading, but can not fix it. Could you help?

I also list part of my data at the bottom.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.counties {
  fill: none;
}

.states {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var unemployment = d3.map();

var path = d3.geoPath();

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1, 10])
    .rangeRound([600, 860]);

var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 10])
    .range(d3.schemeBlues[6]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "key")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,40)");

g.selectAll("rect")
  .data(color.range().map(function(d) {
      d = color.invertExtent(d);
      if (d[0] == null) d[0] = x.domain()[0];
      if (d[1] == null) d[1] = x.domain()[1];
      return d;
    }))
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("height", 8)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d[0]); });

g.append("text")
    .attr("class", "caption")
    //.attr("x", x.range()[0])
    .attr("x", x.range()[0] - 30)
    .attr("y", -6)
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("font-weight", "bold")
    .text("House Price to Income Ratio Rate");

g.call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickSize(13)
    .tickFormat(function(x, i) { return i ? x : x ; })
    .tickValues(color.domain()))
  .select(".domain")
    .remove();

d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "data.tsv", function(d) { unemployment.set(d.id, +d.rate, d.state, d.county); })
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.rate = unemployment.get(d.id)); })
    .attr("d", path)
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d) { var q = d3.format(".2f")
        return 'State:' + d.state + ' ' + d.county + ' ' +d.id + ':' +(q(d.rate)); }
        );

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("class", "states")
      .attr("d", path);
}

</script>
```

Data:

```
id  rate    state   county
47035   0.66    TN  CUMBERLAND
47089   1.26    TN  JEFFERSON
47129   1.08    TN  MORGAN
47155   1.34    TN  SEVIER
47105   1.16    TN  LOUDON
47145   1.1 TN  ROANE
47151   1.26    TN  SCOTT
47067   1.21    TN  HANCOCK
47173   1.03    TN  UNION
47063   1.22    TN  HAMBLEN
47033   1.17    TN  CROCKETT
47157   1.06    TN  SHELBY
47167   1.02    TN  TIPTON
47045   0.75    TN  DYER
47069   1.19    TN  HARDEMAN
47075   1.3 TN  HAYWOOD
47097   1.05    TN  LAUDERDALE
47047   1.38    TN  FAYETTE
47095   1.16    TN  LAKE
47017   1.11    TN  CARROLL
47005   1.19    TN  BENTON
47079   0.99    TN  HENRY
47183   1.06    TN  WEAKLEY
47131   1.1 TN  OBION
47053   1.13    TN  GIBSON
47113   1.26    TN  MADISON
47109   1.25    TN  MCNAIRY
47039   1.37    TN  DECATUR
47071   1.28    TN  HARDIN
47077   1.45    TN  HENDERSON
47023   1.21    TN  CHESTER
47181   1.34    TN  WAYNE
47055   1.16    TN  GILES
47099   1.31    TN  LAWRENCE
47101   1.32    TN  LEWIS
47141   1.45    TN  PUTNAM
47049   1.46    TN  FENTRESS
47133   1.2 TN  OVERTON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that you are accessing the datum of each geographic feature, not rows in the tsv, here:

```
 .text(function(d) { var q = d3.format(".2f")
        return 'State:' + d.state + ' ' + d.county + ' ' +d.id + ':' +(q(d.rate)); }
        );
```

`d` in this funciton contains the feature datum from the geojson, it looks like this:

```
Object { type: "Feature", id: "18121", properties: Object, geometry: Object }  
Object { type: "Feature", id: "39103", properties: Object, geometry: Object }
```

You need to properly map your data and access it with d3.map(). It looks like you are using [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606), and your modification looks intuitive, but this:

```
.defer(d3.tsv, "data.tsv", function(d) { unemployment.set(d.id, +d.rate, d.state, d.county); })
```

results in a data structure like this:

```
Object { $47035: 0.66, $47089: 1.26, $47129: 1.08, $47155: 1.34, $47105: 1.16, $47145: 1.1, $47151: 1.26, $47067: 1.21, $47173: 1.03, $47063: 1.22, 28 more… }
```

I do not believe that d3.map().set() allows for multiple values for each key. Instead you could use an object for the value:

```
.defer(d3.tsv, "data.tsv", function(d) { unemployment.set(d.id, d); })
```

To access a column in the tsv file you then would use a line such as:

```
unemployment.get(d.id).state
```

---

Lastly, it is possible that you have a complete data set for every county, though you might be looking just at select counties, in which case you could add a check to see if data exists (otherwise your d3.map() will return undefined for some counties as you are looking up data for every county.  Something like this would work:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) {  if(unemployment.get(d.id)) { return color(d.rate = unemployment.get(d.id).rate); } else { return "none"; } })
.attr("d", path)
.append("title")
.text(function(d) { var q = d3.format(".2f"); 
    if (unemployment.get(d.id)) {
            return 'State:' + unemployment.get(d.id).state + ' ' + unemployment.get(d.id).county + ' ' +d.id + ':' +(q(d.rate)); 
        }
        else {
            return "no data";
        }
    });
```

[Here's a block](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/e499e569c272cca9b4433649ea218cb2) with it all in action.

*Note that in the above code block d.rate was set when displaying the color, so there is no need to use the unemployment map to set that value when setting the text content afterwards. This was also true in the likely example you were working with, [in this block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606).*